# Soyuz seat - return

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, acceleration

Every astronaut launching on a Soyuz has a seat custom-made [(source)](https://twitter.com/Astro_Feustel/status/867796988766695426). However, I don't believe astronauts typically return on their original Soyuz, and I know that they don't always. In this case, are seats swapped, or are the seats still generic enough that someone else's seat can be used for return?

Comment: See this very nice set of photos https://www.flickr.com/photos/thom_astro/sets/72157650934017941/   
I don't believe that someone else's seat would fit. Only if there are twin astronauts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the crew are going to return on a different Soyuz, they swap the seat liners beforehand.

"One of the first tasks for the Soyuz commanders after arrival was to swap the astronaut’s seat-liners to their new ferry." - 
http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_Spaceflight/iriss/Spacecraft_swap

Comment: For an ISS crew member carried up on the Shuttle, their long duration mission officially began when their seat liner was carried across the hatch interface.